# rostpoic pub & teleop_key

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

reference: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch

I have a question:
when 'roslaunch' launchs the turtlemimic.launch file, there appears two turtles' window. Why can I only use 'rostopic pub' command to drive the turtle1, however, I cannot use 'rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key' command to do that.
the instruction page: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch

the 'rostopic pub' command:
$ rostopic pub /turtlesim1/turtle1/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 1 -- '[2.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, -1.8]'

the 'rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key' command:
$ rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213245/rostpoic-pub-&-teleop_key/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial had the incorrect syntax. It's been [fixed](http://wiki.ros.org/action/diff/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch?action=diff&rev1=24&rev2=25)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2015-07-09**:
I cannot use 'rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key' command to do that. That's my question.

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2015-07-09**:
the unchanged command: $ rostopic pub /turtlesim1/turtle1/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 1 -- '[2.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, -1.8]' works well.